# Not getting correct channel length after putting/recieving from channel

Tags: go

I am learning Go from a Tour of Go . I modified the code given at [Range and Close](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4) page to see the length of channel before and after a value is put in channel in fibonacci func. Also checked length after a value is read in main func's loop.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        fmt.Println("fib - len before: ", len(c))
        c <- x
        fmt.Println("fib - len after : ", len(c))
        x, y = y, x+y
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    go fibonacci(cap(c), c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("main - len now: ", len(c))
        fmt.Println("value recieved: ", i)
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
fib - len before:  0
fib - len after :  0 ////// not expecting this
fib - len before:  0 ////// not expecting this
fib - len after :  1
fib - len before:  1
fib - len after :  2
fib - len before:  2
fib - len after :  3
main - len now:  0 ////// not expecting this
value recieved:  0
main - len now:  2
value recieved:  1
main - len now:  1
value recieved:  1
main - len now:  0
value recieved:  2
```

I am surprised to see that:

1. In Fibonacci func, for iteration 1, the channel length remains 0 after putting value in channel?
2. In main func loop's iteration 1, the channel length shows 0 even though the full fibonacci series is filled up in channel?

I had learnt **len(chan)** gives the number of elements queued (unread) in the channel buffer. But ooutput is constrasting for first iteration of my code. Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: The other goroutine can execute between the channel operation and the print statement.

Comment: "I had learnt len(chan) gives the number of elements queued (unread) in the channel buffer." This is correct. When `fmt.Println("fib - len after : ", len(c))` prints 0 it means there is no unread value in the channel. The one you put into c was taken from c before len(c) is evaluated.